# Obtener datos con modelos Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Obtengo datos de la siguiente manera :

```
        $usuario_editar = User::select('id','name', 'apellidos','dni','celular1','celular2','convencional','estado','rol','email1','email2')->where("dni",$dni)->get();
```

Como hago para obtener el celular1 ?

Trato de hacerlo asi:

```
echo $usuario_editar->id;
```

Pero da error :

Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Comment: eso te devuelve un arreglo, tendrias que indicarle el indice asi: $usuario_editar[0]->id , ahi solo deberias cambiar el 0 por el numero de fila que necesites. si solo necesitas una fila, cambia el get por first y puedes acceder como lo estas haciendo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando construyes una consulta y utilizas `->get();` se devolverá un `array` de objetos. Si no se encuentran elementos se devolverá un `array` vacío.

Cuando utilizas `->first();` se devolverá una sola instancia como `objeto`, si no existe ni una retornará un `null` y si hay más de una utilizará la primera coincidencia encontrada.

Hay algunos métodos como `all()` que por defecto hacen un `->get();` y `find();` que por defecto hacen un `->first();`

[Puedes leer más sobre colecciones acá](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-collections)

En tu caso, debería ser:

```
$usuario_editar[INDICE DE TU ELEMENTO]->id;

//Ejemplo
$usuario_editar[0]->id;
```

Recuerda que tienes funciones que te permitirán debuggear más facil.

```
dd($TU_VARIABLE); // DUMP AND DIE
dump($TU_VARIABLE); // DUMP
```